# Adding constant value column to spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Spark version 2.1 in Databricks. I have a data frame named `wamp` to which I want to add a column named `region` which should take the constant value `NE`. However, I get an error saying `NameError: name 'lit' is not defined` when I run the following command:

```
wamp = wamp.withColumn('region', lit('NE'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you need to import [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?#pyspark.sql.functions.lit)

either

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

will make `lit` available

or something like

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
wamp = wamp.withColumn('region', sf.lit('NE'))
```

Answer (score 4):

muon@ provided the correct answer above. Just adding a quick reproducible version to increase clarity.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 3)], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  4|  3|
+---+---+---+

>>> df = df.withColumn("d", lit(5))
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  4|  3|  5|
+---+---+---+---+
```