# how to make single record in one column in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

how to make single record in one column in pyspark..

like df['col'] = 1 in python

then they get all the col gets 1 automatically

how to fill the one col with single record?

```
## +---+---+-----+
## | A | B |  col| 
## +---+---+-----+
## |  1|  A|    1|     
## |  2|  B|    1|      
## +---+---+-----+
```

df[col]= [1, 1]

df.withColunm('col', 1)

didnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding constant value column to spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033037/adding-constant-value-column-to-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df=df.withColunm('col', lit('1'))
```